# Отправка формы через 3 минуты после показа

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Добрый день подскажите как реализовать подобное на php и js:
1. Нажимается кнопка/ссылка
2. Открывается блок с формой
3. Блок показывается 1 минуту с отсчетом времени
4. Если кнопка "Отправить" не нажата за это время, но после завершения времени независимо, заполнены поля или нет данные отправляются и записываются в БД (либо пустые или заполненные)

Comment: а если юзер закроет браузер за эти три минуты? Если кратко, то примерно так var timer = setInterval(function (){ document.getElementById("YOUR_FORM_ID").submit(); }, 1000*60)

Answer (score 1):

самое простое из **надежных** решений, т.е. учитывающих отключение компьютера, закрытие браузера, смерть пользователя и т.д. это -

отправлять запрос сразу при открытии блока с формой и записи данных в БД на сервере, при этом запрос отправляется с некоторым ключем 'status = start', а если пользователь все таки что-то сделает и сам отправит запрос (submit) то ключ меняет значение на 'status = end' и в БД запись перезаписывается.

для удобства также можно чтобы клиент сам генерировал некоторый ID формы (какое-нибудь большое и потому уникальное значение) - чтобы распознавать, когда данные на сервер приходят от одной формы, а когда от разной (этот ID также хранить в БД) - при таком подходе ключ 'status' уже не нужен - просто каждый раз перезаписывается запись в нужным ID формы

**P.S.**

По деталям (к сожалению не знаю исходный код, так что приведу новый свой):

Основной алгоритм состоит из нескольких частей/этапов:

1. генерация уникального ID
2. создание и отображение формы
3. передача запроса на сервер с данными по умолчанию
4. ожидание отправки данных пользователя
5. закрытие формы

т.е., как я понимаю, есть некоторая форма

```
<form action = 'server.php' method = 'post' class = 'hidden_form'>
    <input type = 'text' name = 'xxx'>
    <input type = 'submit' value = 'отправить'>
</form>
```

Что нужно сделать:

1. отказаться от автоматической кнопки SUBMIT и заменить ее на обычную кнопку BUTTON, на которую будет поставлен обработчик onClick, отвечающий за отправку данных (ну или обработчик вообще можно повесить на любой DOM объект)
2. добавить новый скрытый элемент, содержащий код формы (некоторое уникальное значение
3. сгенерировать некоторое случайное число/строку

   var id = Math.random().toString().substr(2, 32);
4. скрытому элементу назначить сгенерированную случайную строку (если форма уже создана, иначе ее надо предварительно создать)

   $('#form_id').attr('value', id);
5. показать форму пользователю (привел просто как один из способов)

   $('form').toggleClass('hidden_form');
6. сразу после показа формы (или сразу перед, но обязательно после создания) отправить данные на сервер

   $('form').submit();

хотя я предпочитаю делать это через $.ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url:            g_utils._f().net.server_address,
    type:           "POST",
    data: {
        // данные, которые надо взять из формы,
},);
```

7. повесить на кнопку button обработчик события, чтобы можно было выполнять отправку данных на сервер:

   $('#form_submit').on('click', function(){
       $('form').submit();
   });

ну или опять через $.ajax

8. повесить на форму скрытие формы через определённое время

   setTimeout(function(){
       $('form').toggleClass();
   }, 3 * 60 * 1000);

на стороне сервера из полученного запроса извлекаются данные, в том числе и form_id и записываются в БД, где form_id - ключ по которому или INSERT или UPDATE делается

Comment: А как это реализовать? Можете хоть немного кода привести?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sleep.php, ставите sleep(180) перед выполнением записи в базу

Comment: @Владимир, а что именно интересует - скажите, я поподробнее распишу

Comment: Вот как именно после завершения таймера отправить форму в базу

Comment: Владимир, мое предложение - вообще отказаться от таймера, с сразу, перед показыванием формы, отправить запрос на сервер с теми данными, которые должны были бы быть отправлены по таймеры, когда пользователь нажимает кнопку "отправить", то данные отправляются еще раз и перезаписываются в БД. Отправку на сервер я делаю обычно через $.ajax(object).
Сейчас в своем ответе допишу детали